# Open chrome:// URL in a new tab from bookmark

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

Why doesn't this bookmarklet work in Chrome?

```
javascript:window.open('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData');
```

But this does?

```
javascript:window.open('http://www.google.com');
```

Is there any way to open `chrome://settings` in a **new tab** from bookmark in Chrome? Using the link to `chrome://settings` directly in the bookmark works, but it doesn't force it to open in a new tab.

Comment: Probably will help: http://superuser.com/q/526858

Comment: Boo, that's unfortunate. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done due to security risks. See https://superuser.com/q/526858

Other options are keyboard shortcuts

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>
- OS X: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>

Or simply just a bookmark to `chrome://settings` and remember to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> click or middle mouse button click to open in new tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you bookmark just

```
chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
```

You can use **middle click** mouse button to open the bookmark in a new tab but the focus will not be on it though.